# dynamic_sampling hint in queries causing issues in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracle12c

We got told by dba that our application causes troubles on servers.
There are queries that start like following:

```
SELECT /* DS_SVC */ /*+ dynamic_sampling(0) no_sql_tune no_monitoring
optimizer_features_enable(default) no_parallel result_cache(snapshot=3600)
OPT_ESTIMATE(@"innerQuery", TABLE, "THIS_#21", SCALE_ROWS=0.0007347778778) 
*/ SUM(C1) FROM ...
```

and they crash server, we receive ORA-12537.
We are using NHibernate, but I am fairly sure those queries are not generated by our application. The queries just have no meaning in business logic, they are some random joins. We don't have sql trace rights, but in logs that dba gives us those queries are executed under our module name.
I googled and found out that DS_SVC is a comment for some service queries that Oracle12 uses in dynamic sampling.

Our queries not exactly complex, couple of left joins with rownum limit 1000.

So the question is - can I say those DS_SVC queries are a problem on dba side? If so, where can I get some docs to prove it?

Comment: Perhaps the queries are generated by NHibernate itself?

Comment: Guys, DS_SVC is in those queues, should belong to optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have added /*+ dynamic_sampling(0) */ hint in our queries. It helped, the exception is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 12c bug. See if changing this helps. Can ask Oracle support as well.

```
ALTER SESSION SET “_fix_control”=’7452863:0′
```

https://www.pythian.com/blog/performance-problems-with-dynamic-statistics-in-oracle-12c/

DYNAMIC_SAMPLING hint is used to let CBO collect
cardinality during run time.

> Looks like algorithm has been changed in 12c and dynamic sampling is
>   triggered in a broader set of use cases. This behavior can be disabled
>   at statement, session or system level using the fix control for the
>   bug 7452863. For example, ALTER SESSION SET
>   “_fix_control”=’7452863:0′;

Comment: These is some woodoo in EclipseLink (and also possibly in Hibernete) has ability to execute a particular SQL statement whenever you withdraw a connection from pool.

Comment: Check with your DBA to set it at SYSTEM (DB instance) level. ALTER SYSTEM SET “_fix_control”=’7452863:0′;

Answer (score 2):

Those queries are generated by the optimizer itself. The feature is called "Dynamic sampling". Until 11g this was by default used only when there were no stats on tables.

Since 12c Dynamic sampling can also be triggered by other new feature "Adaptive execution plans". For example in situations where histograms are missing on columns.

Generally this is quite complex DBA stuff to deal with. There are various ways how to fix "Adaptive exec plans" or to disable them partially/completely.

Best you can do, is to contact Oracle support.

Comment: That's probably our case, trying to convince our dba to look into it

Comment: This is a new 12c feature, and it will take some time to settle down.